# How to find number of decimal digits for currency in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to find a number of decimal digits for currency (e.g. 2 for USD, 0 for yen) in Javascript?

Comment: Maybe the `Intl.NumberFormat` method [`formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts) could help.

Comment: If you mind about your downvotes, you may choose between : No attempt / No code / No research / Unclear what you're asking [on this place](https://idownvotedbecau.se/).

Comment: @MisterJojo I fail to see what's unclear. Given a currency, find out how many decimal digits it has. What information is missing in order for the question to be answerable?

Comment: @MisterJojo also, no attempt and no code only make sense for a debugging question. This is not a debugging question but a how-to question.

Comment: @MisterJojo It doesn't make sense to add smth like "I didn't manage to find an answer on SO" in the question. Please refer to the duplicate if you find any. And I dont think it is possible to improve this question with code. I can give example in `dart` language, but I don't think it improves the question

Comment: @VLAZ you are wrong about the interlocutor, I only proposed possibilities of answers to the downvotes. Personally I also receive inexplicable downvotes and this is something that I do not endorse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of decimal positions can be extracted using [`Intl.NumberFormat#formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts). It returns an array of formatting.

```js
const numberFormatUSD = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
const numberFormatEUR = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' });
const numberFormatJPY = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' });

const num = 1234.567;

console.log("--- USD ---");
console.log(numberFormatUSD.formatToParts(num));
console.log("--- EUR ---");
console.log(numberFormatEUR.formatToParts(num));
console.log("--- JPY ---");
console.log(numberFormatJPY.formatToParts(num));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

This can then be programmatically parsed to find `type: "fraction"` and retrieve its length. If no such part is found, then the length is zero:

```js
function findLengthOfFraction(currency) {
  const numberFormatUSD = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency });
  return numberFormatUSD.formatToParts(1)
    .find(part => part.type === "fraction")
    ?.value.length ?? 0;
}

console.log("USD:", findLengthOfFraction("USD"));
console.log("EUR:", findLengthOfFraction("EUR"));
console.log("JPY:", findLengthOfFraction("JPY"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find the number of decimal digits for a currency value in JavaScript.

This function takes a currency code as input and returns the corresponding number of decimal digits for that currency.

```js
function getDecimalDigitsForCurrency(currencyCode) {
  const currencyInfo = {
    USD: 2, // United States Dollar
    EUR: 2, // Euro
    JPY: 0, // Japanese Yen
  };
  return currencyInfo[currencyCode] || 2;
}

const currencyCode = 'USD';
const decimalDigits = getDecimalDigitsForCurrency(currencyCode);
console.log(`Currency ${currencyCode} has ${decimalDigits} decimal digits.`);
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your applications here's what I came up with. You might find more optimized solutions later.

I don't know what format your number is in; more specifically if it is an actual number (123) or a string of a number ("123"), so I supported both.

```js
function getDigitPlaces(input) {
    var transInput = parseFloat(input);
    
    if (transInput % 1 === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return String(transInput).split(".")[1].length;
    }
}
```

The transInput variable takes the input to the function and converts it into a number if needed.

The first if statement checks to see if the converted number is an integer (a number without a decimal) as integers don't have a decimal to check for. I did this by evaluating the number modulo 1, which is fancy math jargon for taking everything before the decimal out of the number. If this value is zero, the number did not have anything after the decimal, or no decimal at all.

If the aforementioned condition is false, the function knows there is a decimal, and will isolate the numbers after the decimal by converting the number back to a string, and splitting the string at the decimal point. All that is left is to find the length of the string with the numbers after the decimal.

I hope this helped!

Comment: 1. No need to reinvent [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) 2. That's not what the question asks for. It asks to find the decimal digits for a currency.